# I'm having hard time understanding this solution to a direct proof of a algebraic statement, can someone explain why the following happens.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For any positive real numbers, x and y, $x+y \geq \sqrt{xy} $

Assume that for real numbers, $x$ and $y$, $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ . We will show that $x+y \geq \sqrt{xy}$ .

Since $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ , then $xy > 0$. Also, $ x^2 > 0$ and $ y^2>0$ . Therefore,

$ x^2+xy+y^2>0 \quad$          *(how did xy get here and remained positive)*

Add $xy$  to both sides to get: $\quad$ *(why add xy to both sides and where does it come from?)*

$ x^2+2xy+y^2>xy$

Since $ (x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$

$(x+y)^2>xy$

Taking the square root of both sides gives:

$(x+y)>\sqrt{xy}$

Since $(x+y)>\sqrt{xy}$ , it is also true that $(x+y)\geq\sqrt{xy}$              $ \quad \square$

Comment: To your first question: that line is just using the fact that the sum of three positive numbers is still positive. To your second question: somebody had a clever idea about a way to prove this statement—that clever idea involved adding $xy$ to both sides right there—and the idea ended up working, making a complete proof! Proofs have structural/logical steps, where we can figure out what we need to do and it's pretty rigid; but they also often have clever steps, where we use our understanding of math to think of a strategy that completes the less routine parts of the proof.

Comment: The fact that $x^2$, $y^2$, and $xy$ are all positive implies that their sum is necessarily positive. Adding $xy$ to both sides of $x^2+xy+y^2>0$ was done to get the expression $x^2+2xy+y^2$, which factors nicely.

Comment: @peter Hi, thank you for your response. I understand the idea of the first line what I don't understand is how was the xy able to get there without changing to a negative sign.

Comment: @young.coder131 You know that $x$ and $y$ are both positive so their product must also be positive.  You're not using the prior equation.  You're just using the fact that because $x$ and $y$ are both positive, all quantities on the left-hand side of the inequality are positive.  You could equally well just add $385.956$ to the left-hand side and have the inequality remain true.  It's just more useful to add $xy$.

Comment: @RobertShore Holy brain fart moment I see now, is it x2+xy+y2>0 so after some math it can be equal to the last part (x+y)>√xy? right? is that the reason why the number are squared?

Comment: @young.coder131 I'm not sure what you're asking, but the goal of the proof is to be able to compare a number that's easy to handle to $xy$.